# Using class members without mentioning class name

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

I have a global class and an asp.net page. I want use globally declared singleton members without re-declaring the class name.

for example:

Panel.cs:

```
public class Panel {
    public static Panel P = new Panel();
    private Panel() {

    }
    public void DoSomething() {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Everything is OK!");
    }
}
```

sample.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class temp_sample :System.Web.UI.Page {
    Panel p = Panel.P;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        //regular:
        myP.DoSomething();

        //or simply:
        Panel.P.DoSomething();

        //it both works, ok
        //but i want to use without mentioning 'Panel' in every page
        //like this:
        P.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Thank you very much!

Comment: So you're looking for a singleton pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Create base class inherited from Page

```
class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

and put your `p` property there once.

Than just inherit your pages from `MyPage` instead of `System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: good idea but, i will have to change every new page. is this possible o use 'like a static class'

Comment: @mustafaöztürk are you familiar with static extensions? Might help to do what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @Anri that is exactly what i was thinking

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're just looking to implement the singleton pattern (avoid scoping a `Panel` property within each page):

```
public class Panel
{
    #region Singleton Pattern
    public static Panel instance = new Panel();
    public static Panel Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
    private Panel()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Everything is OK!");
    }
}
```

Then reference it simply using:

```
Panel.Instance.DoSomething();
```